# iOS fragment shaders with multiple outputs

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl, fragment-shader

Is it possible to write GLSL ES fragment shaders under iOS that generate multiple RGB outputs and have (for example) one sent to the screen and one sent to a texture?

Under normal GLSL I guess this would be done by writing to gl_FragColor[i] from the fragment shader. However, it seems that GLSL ES 2.0 only supports a single color output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 does not support FBOs with multiple render targets. Therefore, GLSL ES also does not support it.

NVIDIA [has an extension for it](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/NV/GL_NV_draw_buffers.txt), but obviously that only works on NVIDIA's hardware.